# How to install TPC-E EGen using gcc 4.8 (or above)?

Tags: database, transactions, benchmarking

I am stuck with the installation of TPC-E EGen on Mac OS X (or Linux). I have downloaded the workload generator from TPC website : www.tpc.org/tpce/egen-download-request.asp but I failed to build it.

When using the following command for building the utilities:

```
cd Utilities/prj/GNUMake/
make
```

I receive the following error:

```
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/DateTime.d: No such file or directory
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/EGenVersion.d: No such file or directory
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/error.d: No such file or directory
../../obj/locking.d:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

which is not a meaningful error and does not help in how to resolve the issue.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problems:

1- in EGenStandardTypes.h, I had to replace

```
\#if defined  (__unix) || (_AIX)
```

by

```
\#if defined(unix) || defined(\__unix__) || defined(\__unix) || defined(\__APPLE__) && defined(\__MACH__) || (_AIX)
```

in order to make this part of code work for Mac OS X as well.

2- in DateTime.cpp and error.cpp

I had to comment out `#error` directive usages, as my current version of GCC did not support it.