# Generate data from TPC-E using Mac os

Tags: c++, macos, data-generation, tpc

I'm trying to generate data from the TPC-E benchmark using macOS:

When using the following commands:

```
cd Utilities/prj/GNUMake/

make
```

I get:

```
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/DateTime.d: No such file or directory
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/EGenVersion.d: No such file or directory
../../prj/GNUMake/Makefile.EGenUtilities:136: ../../obj/error.d: No such file or directory
../../obj/locking.d:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I followed the instructions presented here [How to install TPC-E EGen using gcc 4.8 (or above)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635373/how-to-install-tpc-e-egen-using-gcc-4-8-or-above), but I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The current release of TPC-E is v1.14.0, which is quite stable, and as such hasn't been updated in 5 years, the tools do not compile cleanly with the latest C++ compilers (eg, gcc/clang).

I just change the operating system, macOS ==> windows, and it works perfectly.